# MATLAB: Rearranging feature matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, reshape

I have a feature matrix of size `~1M x 3` where the columns are `doc#,wordID#,wordcount`

What's a fast way in Matlab to rearrange this feature matrix so it is instead of size `#docs x # unique words` i.e.

`(length(unique(featurematrix(:,1))) x length(unique(featurematrix(:,2)))`

so that each row instead represents an entire document, each column represents a different word, and the values are the `wordcounts` from the 3rd column of the original matrix?

I started writing a bunch of loops, but had the feeling there's probably some short idiomatic way to do this already built-in to Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to accomplish this

```
data = [1, 1, 1;
        1, 2, 2;
        1, 5, 3;
        2, 1, 4;
        2, 3, 5];

result = accumarray(data(:,1:2), data(:,3))
%   1     2     0     0     3
%   4     0     5     0     0
```

Alternately you could use `sparse`

```
result = full(sparse(data(:,1), data(:,2), data(:,3)))
```

Comment: Perfect that's both fast and short, thanks! Accepting this answer once it allows.

Comment: Any suggestion on which would might be preferred for a matrix of resulting size ~(15k, 60k) or are they both very similar?

Comment: @Jake Well how sparse is the data? If it's sparse (you have a lot of zeros) then you could do the `sparse` solution without the `full` and keep it as sparse. If it's not sparse, they likely have similar performance. I personally prefer the `accumarray` because it's cleaner.

Comment: It's >99% sparse. It seems `accumarray` runs about 10% faster in this case. I think I'm going to go with `accumarray` even though it's very sparse because memory doesn't seem to be an issue. Thanks, much appreciated.